# ASP.NET MVC - Change attribute each of element Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in HTML:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Dishes.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(f => Model.Dishes[i].Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control text-center lt-spinner", @min ="0", @max = "4", data_spy = "numberOnly", @aria_labelledby = "fr-newDiningForm" } })
}
```

Dish1: id: "Dishes_0__Quantity" name: "Dishes[0].Quantity"

Dish2: id: "Dishes_1__Quantity" name: "Dishes[1].Quantity"
v.v...

And I want to change attr `max` of `Dishes[i].Quantity` by Js:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dishCount; i++)
{
    $("#Dishes[i].Quantity").attr({ "max": number });
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Isn't `@class` Objective-C? I've never seen an at sign used in JavaScript in that manner...

Comment: the first time i have changed each element of array by Js. It's @class of C#, I used MVC

Comment: You need to post an example of what the real HTML is. That is meaningless to those not proficient in C# (like me)

Answer (score 0):

I add a class to my HTML code:

```
... new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control text-center lt-spinner number-quantity", @min ="0", @max = "4", ...
```

and change my Js code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dishCount; i++)
{
    $(".number-quantity").attr({ "max": number });
}
```

And it worked.